# Calculate Critical Value

Tags: probability, statistics

Experience in investigating insurance claims shows that the average cost to process a claim is approximately normally distributed with a mean of 80 dollars. New cost-cutting measures were started and a sample of 25 claims was tested. The sample mean of the costs to process these claims was %76 and the sample standard deviation of the costs was $10. We would like to test whether the cost-cutting measures seem to be working at the 5% significance level.
Find the critical value for this test.

I need help please.

I have calculated that

H0: µ = 80 -->null hypothesis

H1: µ < 80 -->alternative hypothesis

here is the t-table
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find the critical value you have to use the table of the t-Distribution. What ist the value of $\alpha$ and how many degrees of freedom do you have here ?

greetings,

calculus

Comment: Critical value for a one-tailed test (the alternative hypothesis shows a specific direction) can be found using a z-table at .05 level of significance. So can u help me out with this Sir? Can u show me the procedure please?

Comment: In my opinion you have to use the t-Distribution. You don´t have standard deviation of the population. As I said, I would look up the critical value in the table of the t-Distribution.

Comment: and can you help me finding the test statistic please? here is what I solved. can u tell is it correct or not? z = (76 - 80)/(10/√25)

Comment: The value ist correct. :) As I said, for me  this is the test value T. The critical value, $t_c$, has to be looked up in the table of the t-Distribution.

Comment: Can you tell me the Tc value by looking up in the table I have uploaded please

Comment: We have df of 80-1=79 and a significance level of 95%. In this case you can see, that $t_c$ must be smaller than 2: $t_c < T$ What is your conclusion, now ?

Comment: the value of T comes out to be -2 sir. Then Tc must be smaller then -2 I guess.

Comment: My fault. You have to take the absolute value of T: $t_c < |T|$

Comment: So what will be tc in your opinion sir?

Comment: Also If the null hypothesis is true this should have a t-distribution with 24 degrees of freedom. So we would reject the null hypothesis if T<c where Pr(T<c∣null)=0.05. Am I rite sir?

Comment: "So what will be tc in your opinion sir?" $1.990<t_c<2$. Look at the table "So we would reject the null hypothesis if $|T|<t_c$" No, you accept it.

Comment: I find tc 1.960 am I rite Sire?

Comment: As I wrote it is $1.990 < t_c < 2$ In the last row of your table there are written the values for the confidence level. We have a level of 0,95. Then you look in the column for 0,95 and searching for the two rows with df 60 and 80. What values are there ?

Comment: 2 and 1.990 sir

Comment: Yes, sir. Now you have to make a decision. Do you accept the null hypothesis or not ? You reject the null hypothesis, if $|T|>t_c$-in the other case you accept it.

Comment: there are two values of tc. so should we take there average then we conclude our final result?

Comment: You can take the average. But that is not really the point. What we sure know is, that $1.990<t_c<2$. This is enough to say if $|T|>t_c$ is true. Yes it is. So you can reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me sir. I have a one last question that what is your conclusion about the cost cutting measures?

Comment: cost-cutting measures seem to be working at the 5% significance level, because the null hypothesis has been rejected.