# calculate critical value from confidence level - hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I was learning hypothesis testing at https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/266 and the one thing that I am not getting is how for a given level of significance ($\alpha$), critical value ($\mathcal{Z}_0$) is computed ?

I went through [Calculate Critical Value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766122/calculate-critical-value) where a similar question was posted. There it was suggested that there is a table for the concerned distribution that could be consulted. This translates to reading values off a normal distribution table in my case since I am working with only normal distributions. Any other way other than reading table.

How is $\mathcal{Z}_0$ calculated (given the level of significance $\alpha$) ? Can it be done using a standard scientific calculator ?

Comment: It will depend on the particular calculator:  for example the [Casio FX-85GTPLUS](http://www.casio.co.uk/products/calculators/scientific-calculators/product/?v=FX-85GTPLUSWESB-UH) does not have the normal distribution but the [Casio FX-991ESPLUS](http://www.casio.co.uk/products/calculators/scientific-calculators/product/?v=FX-991ESPLUS-SB-UH) does

Comment: OK...but what is the process, I mean do we compute some integral, derivative etc. or follow some standard process...I am interested to compute if I am given only a pen, paper (assuming my calculator does not support the calculation) ?

Comment: Without a calculator or computer with a built-in function, you will want to use tables.  You will not be able to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\, dx$ by hand, though there are approximations